# Guidance for statistical analysis on academic collaborations

Tags: correlation, descriptive-statistics, computational-statistics

I am currently engaged in a research project involving data analysis in the field of academic publications and author collaborations.

The dataset I'm working with includes information such as Publication Title, Publication Year, Citations, Gender of the First Author, Genders of other authors.

| Pub Title | Year | Citations | 1st Auth Gender | Other Auth Genders |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| example_name1 | 2023 | 0 | male | ['male', 'male', 'female'] |
| example_name2 | 2023 | 0 | female | ['male', 'male', 'male', 'female'] |
| example_name3 | 2022 | 3 | male | ['male', 'male', 'male'] |
| example_name4 | 2023 | 1 | female | ['male', 'male', 'male'] |
| example_name5 | 2022 | 3 | male | ['female', 'male'] |

I'm interested in exploring several specific associations within this dataset:

1. I'm looking to analyze whether there are any patterns in the sequence of male/female first authors and their co-authors in the articles. Specifically, I want to identify if there are any trends in the gender composition of co-authors in relation to the gender of the first author.
2. Another aspect I'm keen to investigate is whether the gender of the corresponding author is predominantly male or female based on the gender of the first author.

I am seeking advice on the appropriate statistical techniques.

Comment: What is the motivation to perform this research? Is there a particular reason that you believe that the relationship between first author sex and sex of the authors is of interest? (Motivations could be: there's a model for a causal relationship that you wish to test. There's no causal model, but a statistical model could be used in some application, like predictions. For both of these two situations I have problems in imagining how they apply to this question)

Comment: The most interesting part is how to find and express the patterns in the 'Other Auth Genders' variable. One could look at the last author gender/sex, and the the overal ratio of genders/sexes, but possibly you are also after other patterns? But, is there more? (I can imagine the average relative position of the authors of some gender could be of interest)

Comment: What are you planning to do with authors where their sex is hard to determine from their name?

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus i created female and male ratios for the other authors. When I just analysed the distribution of these ratios, I noticed that there is a higher female ratio in years or publications where there were more female first authors. I want to somehow dig deeper to ensure that I am not just implying something that might not be necessarily related.

Comment: What relationship is it that you imply? could you make that more explicit. And for your motivation, again the same question, what motivates the motivation. Why do you analyse the ratios of male/female other authors for a particular year in relation to the ratios male/female first authors in that same year?

Comment: Welcome to cv, aveyilagrun! Looks like an interesting project :-) I wonder why this question has been closed. Maybe it is the last paragraph, asking for ideas, literature, code? I think you have got a good answer already, but if you want to have the question reopened, you could try to cut down on the last paragraph.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus i basically want to see whether female researchers are more inclined to collaborate with females or vice versa.

Comment: @aveyilagrun isn't there a large variation in the ratios of men and women for different fields of research and doesn't that make it very likely that women are more likely to collaborate with women and men more likely to collaborate with men (and very straightforward to test, just compare with a completely random distribution of men and women)? Given your question (which mentions 'exploring') I was imagining that you were onto some more complicated relationships (and in that case what sort of relationships are you thinking about, is it a test of some theory, or is it to test equality? Etc.).

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus testing the equality and potential bias essentially, but i am comparing it across different titles and years, which is of interest on whether these metrics change

Comment: Looks like the question has been edited to remove lots of information. Previous comments and the existing answer refer to things I don't see. In the current form there is far too little information to say anything, however apparently more information was there and has been removed for reasons I don't understand.

Comment: @Christian I rolled the question back to its preceding version to rectify the destruction.

Comment: OP: Can you get IDs for the authors in order to distinguish between them? If so I can recommend something quite useful.

Comment: @ChristianHennig I gave up, that's why

Comment: I have now locked the question to prevent unilateral destruction of its content, which has now repeatedly occurred.  If you have a concern about that, then please raise that in a flag or meta discussion.  Although we do have a process to redact posts that inadvertently reveal privileged or sensitive information, that would not apply to this one with its artificial data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to CV.

For your first question:

> I want to identify if there are any trends in the gender composition
> of co-authors in relation to the gender of the first author.

As an aside, it's sex, not gender. "Male" and "female" are sexes, "masculine" and "feminine" are genders.

You could first turn the other authors field into a "proportion male" variable. Then you could do a beta regression with that proportion as the dependent variable and the sex of the 1st author as the independent variable (if you're interested in year, add that as a covariate).

For your second question, another logistic regression should work.

Comment: I wouldn't do a regression and instead just try to visualise the patterns, e.g. plot density estimates of the distributions of the proportions, as function of the first author (or possibly a scatter plot of proportions and citations, or plots that visualize changes in time). The reason is that regression is just giving a single parameter indication of the effect size and significance. But in this application the significance and effect size won't be an issue (there's likely gonna be differences and the question is not if there are difference, instead it's more about how there are differences).

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus Good points. I'd probably do both. Graphs are almost always a good idea.